# merge, heap, and quick sort counts are not coming out properly

Tags: python, sorting

```
import random, timeit

#Qucik sort
def quick_sort(A,first,last):
    global Qs,Qc
    if first>=last: return
    left, right= first+1, last
    pivot = A[first]
    while left <= right:
        while left <=last and A[left]<pivot:
            Qc= Qc+1
            left= left + 1
        while right > first and A[right] >= pivot:
            Qc=Qc+1
            right = right -1
        if left <= right:   
            A[left],A[right]=A[right],A[left]
            Qs = Qs+1
            left= left +1
            right= right-1

    A[first],A[right]=A[right],A[first]
    Qs=Qs+1
    quick_sort(A,first,right-1)
    quick_sort(A,right+1,last)


#Merge sort
def merge_sort(A, first, last): # merge sort A[first] ~ A[last]
    global Ms,Mc
    if first >= last: return
    middle = (first+last)//2
    merge_sort(A, first, middle)
    merge_sort(A, middle+1, last)
    B = []
    i = first
    j = middle+1
    while i <= middle and j <= last:
        Mc=Mc+1
        if A[i] <= A[j]:
            B.append(A[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            B.append(A[j])
            j += 1
    for i in range(i, middle+1): 
        B.append(A[i])
        Ms=Ms+1
    for j in range(j, last+1):
        B.append(A[j])
    for k in range(first, last+1): A[k] = B[k-first]

#Heap sort
def heap_sort(A):
    global Hs, Hc
    n = len(A)
    for i in range(n - 1, -1, -1):
        while 2 * i + 1 < n:
            left, right = 2 * i + 1, 2 * i + 2
            if left < n and A[left] > A[i]:
                m = left
                Hc += 1
            else:
                m = i
                Hc += 1
            if right < n and A[right] > A[m]:
                m = right
                Hc += 1
            if m != i:
                A[i], A[m] = A[m], A[i]
                i = m
                Hs += 1
            else:
                break                               
    for i in range(n - 1, -1, -1):
        A[0], A[i] = A[i], A[0]
        n -= 1
        k = 0
        while 2 * k + 1 < n:
            left, right = 2 * k + 1, 2 * k + 2
            if left < n and A[left] > A[k]:
                m = left
                Hc += 1
            else:
                m = k
                Hc += 1
            if right < n and A[right] > A[m]:
                m = right
                Hc += 1
            if m != k:
                A[k], A[m] = A[m], A[k]
                k = m
                Hs += 1
            else:
                break

#

def check_sorted(A):
    for i in range(n-1):
        if A[i] > A[i+1]: return False
    return True

#

#

Qc, Qs, Mc, Ms, Hc, Hs = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

n = int(input())
random.seed()
A = []
for i in range(n):
    A.append(random.randint(-1000,1000))
B = A[:]
C = A[:]

print("")
print("Quick sort:")
print("time =", timeit.timeit("quick_sort(A, 0, n-1)", globals=globals(), number=1))
print("  comparisons = {:10d}, swaps = {:10d}\n".format(Qc, Qs))
print("Merge sort:")
print("time =", timeit.timeit("merge_sort(B, 0, n-1)", globals=globals(), number=1))
print("  comparisons = {:10d}, swaps = {:10d}\n".format(Mc, Ms))

print("Heap sort:")
print("time =", timeit.timeit("heap_sort(C)", globals=globals(), number=1))
print("  comparisons = {:10d}, swaps = {:10d}\n".format(Hc, Hs))


assert(check_sorted(A))
assert(check_sorted(B))
assert(check_sorted(C))
```

I made the code that tells how much time it takes to sort list size n(number input) with 3 ways of sorts. However, I found that my result is quite unexpected.

```
Quick sort:
time = 0.0001289689971599728
  comparisons =        474, swaps =        168

Merge sort:
time = 0.00027709499408956617
  comparisons =        541, swaps =         80

Heap sort:
time = 0.0002578190033091232
  comparisons =        744, swaps =        478

Quick sort:
time = 1.1767549149953993
  comparisons =    3489112, swaps =     352047

Merge sort:
time = 0.9040642600011779
  comparisons =    1536584, swaps =      77011

Heap sort:
time = 1.665754442990874
  comparisons =    2227949, swaps =    1474542

Quick sort:
time = 4.749891302999458
  comparisons =   11884246, swaps =     709221

Merge sort:
time = 3.1966246420051903
  comparisons =    3272492, swaps =     154723

Heap sort:
time = 6.2041203819972
  comparisons =    4754829, swaps =    3148479
```

as you see, my results are very different from what I learned. Can you please tell me why quick sort is not the fastest in my code? and why merge is the fastest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you are choosing the first element of the array as the pivot in quicksort. Now, consider the order of the elements of the unsorted array. Is it random? How do you generate the input array?

You see, if the pivot was either the min or max value of the aray, or somewhere close to the mind/max value, the running time of quicksort in that case (worst case) will be in the order of O(n^2). That is because on each iteration, you are partitioning the arry by breaking off only one element.

For optimal quicksort performance of O(n log n), your pivot should be as close to the median value as possible. In order to increase the likelihood of that being the case, consider initially picking 3 values at random in from the array, and use the median value as the pivot. Obviously, the more values you choose the median from initially the better the probability that your pivot is more efficient, but you are adding extra moves by choosing those values to begin with, so it's a trade off. I imagine one would even be able to calculate exactly how many elements should be selected in relation to the size of the array for optimal performance.

Merge sort on the other hand, always has the complexity in the order of O(n log n) irrespective of input, which is why you got consistent results with it over different samples.

TL:DR my guess is that the input array's first element is very close to being the smallest or largest value of that array, and it ends up being the pivot of your quicksort algorithm.